# using POST instead of PUT in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, laravel-routing, http-verbs

I'm using Laravel to build and api based admin control application and I'm using 
Route:resource instead of regular GET and POST methods.

Just realized my hosting provider DOESN'T ALLOW PUT and DELETE now I need to so now I have to use POST and GET methods.

this is what i have

```
Route::resource('contacts', 'Admin\\ContactInfoController',['only' => ['create', 'store', 'update']]);
    Route::get('claims/statuses', 'Admin\\ClaimsController@statusCodes');
    Route::get('claims/costcenters', 'Admin\\ClaimsDetailsController@getCostCentres');
    Route::get('claims/{id}/details', 'Admin\\ClaimsController@details');
    Route::get('claims/{id}/messages', 'Admin\\ClaimsController@messages');
    Route::resource('claims', 'Admin\\ClaimsController',['only' => ['index','store','update','destroy','edit']]);
    Route::resource('claims/details', 'Admin\\ClaimsDetailsController',['only' => ['store','update','destroy']]);
```

What approach might be best in converting my routes from PUT and DELETE to POST and GET?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible that your hosting provider doesn't allow to put or delete request. If you created API it could be the case but in other cases  (you created normal page) you send forms using POST method with hidden field `_method` set to HTTP verb, so if only your provider supports POST method it will work without a problem. You can read [Form method spoofing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing#form-method-spoofing) section about this.

Comment: Nabialek Actually InMotion Hosting disables this by default. So it is possible

Answer (score 0):

Contact your hosting provided to allow put or delete request, it's part of web development and this is quite limiting.

Comment: they actually did. Only way to enable this is to upgrade....I was mislead by InMotion Hosting.

Comment: @Kendall, try to choose a better hosting, dont let them limit you .

Comment: I'm in the mist of doing so however, At the moment the situation requires me to find a temporary solution in the interim. Would you have any suggestions for hosting laravel projects effeciently?